# Swift weak reference going nil even when self keeps existing

Tags: swift, weak-references

I'm trying to figure out why is a weak reference losing its referenced object even after the object keeps existing.

My code looks like:

```swift
MyClass {
    deinit {
        print("I'm being deinited") // This never gets called
    }
    func doConnection(connection: Future<Data, ServerConnectionError>) {
        Future<Void, ServerConnectionError> { complete in
            connection.onSuccess {[weak self] data in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return // This line gets called
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By inspecting the memory graph, I can see that the object referenced by self before the future completes is still alive (judging by the memory address).

Here's what the memory graph for the supposedly missing object looks like after finding its weak reference as nil (MyClass instance in far right):

[image: Memory graph showing two main references to the object]

The upper subtree is the one supposed to hold the object alive, while the bottom one has to do with the current stack execution. The object (blue box) that is referenced by many others in the 3rd level (from right to left) holds a strong reference to an array, which in turn holds a reference to the MyClass instance.

**EDIT**: Problem solved in answer below. Will mark as solved after cooldown passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Ok, so I don't know what was going on, but it fixed itself after multiple attempts to debug it. One thing that is still buggy is that the debugger show `self` as `nil` inside the closure (which added a significant time in the debugging process), but the `guard let` block executes successfully and I get a strong reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Move any capture list containing `self` to the outer-most closure or else it may create a reference cycle:

```
MyClass {
    deinit {
        print("I'm being deinited") // This never gets called
    }
    doConnection(connection: Future<Data, ServerConnectionError>) { [weak self] in
        Future<Void, ServerConnectionError> { complete in
            connection.onSuccess { data in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return // This line gets called
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot place a capture list there, since it is a class method (sorry, forgot to add `func`). Already tried placing the capture list in the `Future<Void...` line  as well with no luck.

Comment: And when you remove this line of code, it deinitializes every time? We are sure this is the culprit?

Comment: Please see my answer. It was all an issue with the compiler I guess, because it fixed itself after a few tries. Also, the debugger was showing me wrong info.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a closure expression captures the properties from its surrounding scope with strong references to those values. But you are defining self to be weak in your closure/promise. You may remove `[weak self]` use `[unowned self]` or move the closure list to the outer block. So long as your instance of MyClass is not deallocated while the promise is being fulfilled. Objects with no strong references are deallocated only when memory pressure triggers garbage collection. However, within ARC, values are deallocated as soon as their **last strong reference is removed**. By making self weak in your closure you are allowing ARC to remove the references to your instance of MyClass when no other strong reference exists, your weak reference will be removed after the instance of MyClass is deinitialized.

Comment: I'm aware that weak means that the object can be deallocated, and I'm fine with that. I don't want to execute my relevant code if the reference is lost. The issue is that the object is still in memory, being strong referenced all the time. Its deinit method is never called, so it never loses all its strong references.